# Group together matched pairs across multiple columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-computing

Thank you for reading.

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Col_A  Col_B   Col_C  Col_D  Col_E  
 1     2       null   null   null  
 1     null    3      null   null  
 null  2       3      null   null  
 null  2       null   4      null  
 1     null    null   null   5
```

Each row consists of a match between two IDs (e.g. ID1 from Col_A matches to ID2 from Col_B on the first row).

In the example above, all 5 IDs are connected (1 is connected to 2, 2 to 3, 2 to 4, 1 to 5). I therefore want to create a new column which clusters all of these rows together so that I can easily access each group of matched pairs:

```
Col_A  Col_B   Col_C  Col_D  Col_E  Group ID
 1     2       null   null   null      1
 1     null    3      null   null      1
 null  2       3      null   null      1
 null  2       null   4      null      1
 1     null    null   null   5         1
```

I have not yet been able to find a similar question, but apologies if this is a duplicate. Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: looks like net work problem ~

Comment: checkout `networkx` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @YOBEN_S and @QuangHoang suggests, you can use networkx library and [Graph Theory connnected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) like this.

Given df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_A': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 1.0, 5: np.nan},
 'Col_B': {0: 2.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan},
 'Col_C': {0: np.nan, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.0, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan},
 'Col_D': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 4.0, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan},
 'Col_E': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 5.0, 5: np.nan},
 'Col_F': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 6.0},
 'Col_G': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 7.0}})

|    |   Col_A |   Col_B |   Col_C |   Col_D |   Col_E |   Col_F |   Col_G |
|---:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|
|  0 |       1 |       2 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |
|  1 |       1 |     nan |       3 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |
|  2 |     nan |       2 |       3 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |
|  3 |     nan |       2 |     nan |       4 |     nan |     nan |     nan |
|  4 |       1 |     nan |     nan |     nan |       5 |     nan |     nan |
|  5 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |       6 |       7 |
```

Use

```
import networkx as nx
d_edge = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_numpy(), axis=1)
G = nx.from_edgelist(d_edge.to_numpy().tolist())
cc_list = list(nx.connected_components(G))
df['groupid'] = d_edge.apply(lambda  x: [n for n, i in enumerate(cc_list) if x[0] in i][0] + 1)
df
```

Output:

```
|    |   Col_A |   Col_B |   Col_C |   Col_D |   Col_E |   Col_F |   Col_G |   groupid |
|---:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|
|  0 |       1 |       2 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |         1 |
|  1 |       1 |     nan |       3 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |         1 |
|  2 |     nan |       2 |       3 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |         1 |
|  3 |     nan |       2 |     nan |       4 |     nan |     nan |     nan |         1 |
|  4 |       1 |     nan |     nan |     nan |       5 |     nan |     nan |         1 |
|  5 |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |     nan |       6 |       7 |         2 |
```

Comment: Cheers this is really helpful - any alternative to using to_numpy()?

Comment: Yes you can use `df.values` for `df.to_numpy()` with older versions of pandas.

Comment: Hi, any alternatives to using networkx / graph theory packages (loop?). This runs slowly on larger datasets (hundreds of thousands of rows). Thanks

Comment: @Joseph0210  Hrm.. I am not aware of a another simple solution.  I am sure you could write a custom function that does the same thing, but I am not sure it will be faster.